# Subversive icon showing revision number of a file in the repository is greater than local one

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-kepler, subversive

I'm using Subversive plugin with Eclipse Kepler.
When I want to work on a file in Eclipse, Is there an icon that can be enabled, showing that the version of the file in the server (revision number) is greater than the one of the local same file ? (without going through 'synchronise with repository')

Comment: How would Eclipse keep such an indicator up to date? Someone else might check in a change at any time making the indicator incorrect.

Comment: may be by sending requests regularly to the server in aim to compare the local and distant files ;) or there would be a push mecanism to alert the clients about recent commits done by the users ...